# Does Adobe AIR Encrypted SQLite Database access or use the encryption in Apple iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, apache-flex, encryption, air

We are submitting an update of our Adobe AIR created app to the Apple App Store. We wish to change our encryption status.

The app was created using AIR 3.7 and uses several Encrypted SQLite Databases and an SSL connection to our server. As a precaution we got the US BIS export notice when we first submitted the app, but during the submit process we received this notice from Apple:

> French authorities have agreed to limit the regulatory approval requirements for Apple’s App Store apps that use, access, implement, or incorporate:
>
> - any encryption algorithm that is yet to be standardized by international standard bodies such as IEEE, IETF, ISO, ITU, ETSI, 3GPP, TIA, etc. or not otherwise published; or
> - standard (e.g., AES, DES, 3DES, RSA) encryption algorithm(s) instead of or in addition to accessing or using the encryption in Apple OS
>
> Consistent with the requirement, Apple will require you to upload a copy of your approved French declaration when you submit your app to the App Store if it meets the criteria described above.

So we decided to not publish to the French app store for our first release.

We now would like to publish to France, but I am not sure if we can state that our encryption is not in addition to accessing or using the encryption in Apple OS . I have found documentation that Encrypted Local Store uses KeyChain, but not that Encrypted SQLite Database does, only that it uses AES encryption.

We do not want to apply for the French import decleration unless really necessary, as it seems like a terribly complex process, in French.

Does anyone know if Encrypted SQLite Database uses that encryption already there in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8AFC5E35-DC79-4082-9AD4-DE1A2B41DAAF.html), *Considerations for using encryption with a database*:

> AIR database encryption uses the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) with Counter with CBC-MAC (CCM) mode.

I can find no indication that it uses a platform-specific method on iOS.